# Setting up multiple SSH key access to Github

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying to configure a remote linux machine to access two distinct git accounts which I own. I keep getting authentication access manifesting in.

```
> git push
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Steps i've taken,

1. Generated a two sets of ssh keys (call them `key1` and `key2`)
2. Generated a config file at `~/.ssh/config`
3. Edited that file

```
    1 # Default github account: key1
      2 Host github.com
      3    HostName github.com
      4    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key1
      5    IdentitiesOnly yes
      6
      7 # Other github account: key2
      8 Host github-key2
      9    HostName github.com
     10    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key2
     11    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

4. Added the `.pub` version to my two git accounts under the user account `settings/ssh keys`.
5. Added them on my VM with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/key1`

I'm unsure really where to go from here and what the next steps are for why this isn't working. I feel like there might be a step i'm missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tl;dr: Add the following entry to your `~/.ssh/config` where `$user` is the GitHub username and `$key` is the private key specified for that user and defined in the setting for that GitHub user:

```
Host github.com-$user
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/$key
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then, configure your git remote URL:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com-$user:$user/$repo
```

Basically, I had a long-running SSH key for work/personal projects, then wanted to add a new key for unrelated side projects. I did all of the steps you outlined in your question, and still got the same error. Doing `$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v' git fetch` showed that git was passing my main user's private key first, and even though it was authenticating correctly as a valid key, that user of course had no permissions on the new user's private repositories.

This post is relevant: https://medium.com/@ordinary.yobi/multiple-ssh-keys-on-github-f75a372d5374

This is my first answer, and I hope it helps. I literally just finished solving this exact problem moments ago, and it was extremely frustrating.

*EDIT:* Whoops, forgot the critical part. Sorry!